# Name a column inside a loop on charactere vector with the current value of the loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr

I have one dataframe (data2) for which I want to add column ("M1", "M2", "M3") based on the presence of some string in another tab (data1). For example, for "M1" value, I want to create a columned name "M1" in data2 containing the value of TOT of a raw if this value is associated to M1 in the data1.
In some case I have in data2 value as follow "t1;t4" and what I want to considere for comparison in data2 is value separated by ; for each row.

For better understanding, there is the outpout I want below.

In order to do that I tried to make a loop on a vector containing all the module values ("M1"..."M3"), filter the data1 for this value, store the corresponding GNE value in a vector, and add the column in data2 with mutate function. I would like to know how to name inside the loop the New column with "M1", "M2" or "M3".

Or if someone have a better idea to obtain the output with another method I would also be usefule for me, as I think this is not the simplest way to do that. In my real data I have 32 new columns to add by this way.

```
data1=data.frame(Module=c("M1", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M3", "M3", "M3"), GNE= c("t1", "t3", "t5", "t8", "t2", "t9", "t12"))


data2=data.frame(ID=c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"), TOT=c("t1;t4", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8;t9", "t9", "t10", "t8-8"))


list=c("M1", "M2", "M3")

> data1
  Module GNE
1     M1  t1
2     M1  t3
3     M2  t5
4     M3  t8
5     M3  t2
6     M3  t9
7     M3 t12

> data2
    ID   TOT
1   A1 t1;t4
2   A2    t2
3   A3    t3
4   A4    t4
5   A5    t5
6   A6    t6
7   A7    t7
8   A8 t8;t9
9   A9    t9
10 A10   t10
11 A11  t8-8
```

```
for (a in list) {
 
 data1_int=data1 %>% filter(Module=={{a}})
 
 data1_int=data1_int$GNE
 
 data2_int=data2 %>% mutate(New1 = map_chr(strsplit(TOT, ";"), ~ str_c(intersect(., data1_int), collapse = ";"))) %>% select(New1)
 
 data2=cbind(data2, data2_int)
 
}
```

```
out=data2=data.frame(ID=c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"), 
                     TOT=c("t1;t4", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8;t9", "t9", "t10", "t8-8"),
                     M1=c("t1", "", "t3", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
                     M2=c("", "", "", "", "t5", "", "", "", "", "", ""),
                     M3=c("", "t2", "", "", "", "", "", "t8;t9", "t9", "", ""))

     ID   TOT M1 M2    M3
1   A1 t1;t4 t1         
2   A2    t2          t2
3   A3    t3 t3         
4   A4    t4            
5   A5    t5    t5      
6   A6    t6            
7   A7    t7            
8   A8 t8;t9       t8;t9
9   A9    t9          t9
10 A10   t10            
11 A11  t8-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach without using a `for` loop.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 %>%
  filter(GNE %in% data2$TOT) %>%
  mutate(col = GNE) %>%
  complete(Module, GNE = data2$TOT, fill = list(col = '')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Module, values_from = col) %>%
  left_join(data2, by = c('GNE' = 'TOT')) %>%
  select(ID, GNE, everything()) %>%
  arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder(ID)))

#    ID    GNE   M1    M2    M3   
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 A1    t1    "t1"  ""    ""   
# 2 A2    t2    ""    ""    "t2" 
# 3 A3    t3    "t3"  ""    ""   
# 4 A4    t4    ""    ""    ""   
# 5 A5    t5    ""    "t5"  ""   
# 6 A6    t6    ""    ""    ""   
# 7 A7    t7    ""    ""    ""   
# 8 A8    t8    ""    ""    "t8" 
# 9 A9    t9    ""    ""    "t9" 
#10 A10   t10   ""    ""    ""
```

Comment: Tnanks for this solution. This is working with these data, but I realized that mine are a  bit more complexe and this is not working on it. The reason is that in data2 some of my values is considered as two (or more) values (for me) as like this "t1;14". If t1 is present with M1 in data1, I want t1 in M1 column in the output. Here t1 in data2 in "t1;t4" is considered different from t1 in data1. What I want to compare is what is separated by ; in data2 with value of GNE in data1. This is the reason why I was using str_split(). I will update my post with this case and another case to considere

Answer (score 1):

try to use `dcast` from `data.table` (or `reshape2`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data1 <- data1 %>% as.data.table()
data2 <- data2 %>% as.data.table()

data2 %>% 
  left_join(data1, by = c("TOT" = "GNE")) %>%   
  dcast(ID + TOT ~ Module, value.var = "TOT", fill = "")

out:
     ID TOT  NA M1 M2 M3
 1:  A1  t1     t1      
 2: A10 t10 t10         
 3:  A2  t2           t2
 4:  A3  t3     t3      
 5:  A4  t4  t4         
 6:  A5  t5        t5   
 7:  A6  t6  t6         
 8:  A7  t7  t7         
 9:  A8  t8           t8
10:  A9  t9           t9
```

if you need to keep order of `ID` (and remove `NA` column):

```
data2 %>% 
  left_join(data1, by = c("TOT" = "GNE")) %>%   
  dcast(ID + TOT ~ Module, value.var = "TOT", fill = "") %>% 
  select(-`NA`) %>%
  arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder(ID)))

out:
     ID TOT M1 M2 M3
 1:  A1  t1 t1      
 2:  A2  t2       t2
 3:  A3  t3 t3      
 4:  A4  t4         
 5:  A5  t5    t5   
 6:  A6  t6         
 7:  A7  t7         
 8:  A8  t8       t8
 9:  A9  t9       t9
10: A10 t10
```

---

after edit its a bit more complicated:

```
data2 %>% 
  tidyr::separate(TOT, into = c("TOT1","TOT2"), sep = "\\;", remove = F) %>% 
  left_join(data1, by = c("TOT1" = "GNE")) %>%
  left_join(data1, by = c("TOT2" = "GNE")) %>%
  
  mutate(TOT2 = ifelse(is.na(Module.y), NA,  TOT2),
         TOT1 = ifelse(is.na(Module.x), NA,  TOT1)) %>%
  tidyr::unite("tmp", c(TOT1, TOT2), na.rm = T, sep = ";") %>%
  mutate(Module = coalesce(Module.x, Module.y)) %>% 
  
  dcast(ID + TOT ~ Module, value.var = "tmp", fill = "") %>%
  select(-`NA`) %>%
  arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder(ID)))

out:
     ID   TOT M1 M2    M3
 1:  A1 t1;t4 t1         
 2:  A2    t2          t2
 3:  A3    t3 t3         
 4:  A4    t4            
 5:  A5    t5    t5      
 6:  A6    t6            
 7:  A7    t7            
 8:  A8 t8;t9       t8;t9
 9:  A9    t9          t9
10: A10   t10            
11: A11  t8-8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. This is working with these data, but I realized that mine are a little bit more complexe and this is not working on it. The reason is that in data2 some of my values is considered as two value (for me) as like this "t1;14". If t1 is present with M1 in data1, I want t1 in M1 column in the output. Here t1 in data2 in "t1;t4" is considered different from t1 in data1. What I want to compare is what is separated by ; in data2 with value of GNE in data1. This is the reason why I was using str_split(). I  updated my post with this case and another case to considere

Comment: check added solution